# Amazon SES Verify .eus domain email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to verify an email with .eus domain (info@xxxXxxx.eus) which is created on 2014, but do not receive the email with the link to it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your email address is a valid one and you have gotten any incoming email. Once you're 100% sure about this. Go to:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-east-1#verified-senders-email:

Click on Verify a new Email Address as shown below:

[image]

And the following popup will show:

[image]

Then, enter your email address there and click on the button: Verify this email address.
If your email address is ok, you shold get the SES email within seconds.